# OLAP CUBE partial processing

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, olap, olap-cube

is there any way to partial processing OLAP CUBE? For example - we have cube with 1 mln records per 1 day. So processing gonna be harder with every new day. Is it possible to process just recently inserted information?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! I would start by reading this good whitepaper that explains cube processing:
http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345142.aspx

Basically you can do a daily ProcessUpdate on your dimensions, partition and ProcessData only the most recent measure group partitions, and ProcessIndexes your cube to rebuild any indexes and aggs that were invalidated during ProcessUpdate.